# Find weekly leaves aggregate for each partner before a specific date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a leave dataset of partners with leave start date and end date, duration of leaves and Last Working Date (LWD). I need to find the sum of leaves for each partner availed four weeks from LWD grouped in each week interval from LWD. Week1 may be considered 7 days from LWD, week2 as the next 7 days and so on.

EDIT: The aim is to find out the number of leaves each partner availed in each of the last four weeks till their departure from the company

Dataset example below, dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format

[image]

I'm looking for an outcome such as:

[image]

I understand there would be a `groupby` followed by `datetime.timedelta(days = 7)`to get to the dates from LWD but confused as to arrive at the final outcome. Any help appreciated. Please note that the weekly sums are not cumulative, only for the span of the specific week

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'EID':[75161,75162,75162,75162,75162,75166,75166,75166,75169,75170],
                   'START_DATE':['30/08/21','01/10/21','18/06/21','12/11/21','14/06/21','22/04/21','22/07/21','23/08/21','24/08/21','25/10/21'],
                   'END_DATE':['30/08/21','01/10/21','18/06/21','12/11/21','14/06/21','23/04/21','23/07/21','23/08/21','26/08/21','25/10/21'],
                   'LWD':['30/08/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/11/21'],
                   'DURATION':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1]
                  })

df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['LWD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LWD'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation isn't very helpful.  Can you elaborate on the computation required as well as the Column heading logic.

Comment: The aim is to find out the number of leaves each partner availed in each of the last four weeks till their departure from the company

Comment: So is it important that the sum be shown by individual week or just the total?

Comment: total leaves availed 7 days before LWD, total leaves availed between 7 and 14 days before LWD, total leaves availed between 21 and 14 days before LWD and total leaves between 21 and 28 days before LWD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note about your example is you need to include the dayfirst=True argument to your statements converting date columns to pd.datetime types.  as shown below:

```
df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
df['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
df['LWD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LWD'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
```

Once you have made that change your datefields should report a consistent and correct date entry as illustrated below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'EID':[75161,75162,75162,75162,75162,75166,75166,75166,75169,75170],
                   'START_DATE':['30/08/21','01/10/21','18/10/21','12/11/21','14/06/21','22/04/21','22/07/21','23/08/21','24/08/21','25/10/21'],
                   'END_DATE':['30/08/21','01/10/21','18/10/21','12/11/21','14/06/21','23/04/21','23/07/21','23/08/21','26/08/21','25/10/21'],
                   'LWD':['30/08/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/11/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/10/21','13/11/21'],
                   'DURATION':[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,3,1]
                  })

df['START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
df['END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['END_DATE'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
df['LWD'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LWD'], infer_datetime_format=True, dayfirst=True)
```

Note: I altered some of your data to add some complexity to the example by having a single ID have leave dates in more than period of interest.

My dataframe looks like:

```
    EID     START_DATE  END_DATE    LWD         DURATION
0   75161   2021-08-30  2021-08-30  2021-08-30  1
1   75162   2021-10-01  2021-10-01  2021-11-13  1
2   75162   2021-10-18  2021-10-18  2021-11-13  1
3   75162   2021-11-12  2021-11-12  2021-11-13  1
4   75162   2021-06-14  2021-06-14  2021-11-13  1
5   75166   2021-04-22  2021-04-23  2021-10-13  2
6   75166   2021-07-22  2021-07-23  2021-10-13  2
7   75166   2021-08-23  2021-08-23  2021-10-13  1
8   75169   2021-08-24  2021-08-26  2021-10-13  3
9   75170   2021-10-25  2021-10-25  2021-11-13  1
```

Now the first step is to add a column which shows the weeks before LWD in which leave has been taken as follows:

```
#define function to calculate timedelta in weeks between two columns
def week_diff(x: pd.datetime, y:pd.datetime) -> int:
    end = x.dt.to_period('W').view(dtype='int64')
    start = y.dt.to_period('W').view(dtype='int64')
    return end-start  

df['wks_delta'] = week_diff(df['LWD'], df['START_DATE'])
```

Results in:

```
     EID    START_DATE  END_DATE    LWD         DURATION    wks_delta
0   75161   2021-08-30  2021-08-30  2021-08-30  1           0
1   75162   2021-10-01  2021-10-01  2021-11-13  1           6
2   75162   2021-10-18  2021-10-18  2021-11-13  1           3
3   75162   2021-11-12  2021-11-12  2021-11-13  1           0
4   75162   2021-06-14  2021-06-14  2021-11-13  1           21
5   75166   2021-04-22  2021-04-23  2021-10-13  2           25
6   75166   2021-07-22  2021-07-23  2021-10-13  2           12
7   75166   2021-08-23  2021-08-23  2021-10-13  1           7
8   75169   2021-08-24  2021-08-26  2021-10-13  3           7
9   75170   2021-10-25  2021-10-25  2021-11-13  1           2
```

We can than filter this dataframe and groupby("EID", 'wks_delta') using the following:

```
df = df[df['wks_delta'] <= 4]
df1 = df.groupby(['EID', 'wks_delta']).sum()
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

resulting in:

```
    EID    wks_delta    DURATION
0   75161   0            1
1   75162   0            1
2   75162   3            1
3   75170   2            1
```

The by applying the following:

```
def computeLeavePeriods(prds: list, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    row_index = list(df["EID"].unique())
    rows = len(row_index)
    cols = len(prds)
    rslt = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        rslt[row_index.index(df.iloc[r]['EID'])][df.iloc[r]['wks_delta']] += df.iloc[r]['DURATION']
    return pd.DataFrame(data= rslt, columns=prds, index=row_index)  

computeLeavePeriods(['1-LWD', '2-LWD', '3-LWD', '4-LWD'], df1)
```

we get the final result:

```
      1-LWD 2-LWD   3-LWD   4-LWD
75161   1    0       0       0
75162   1    0       0       1
75170   0    0       1       0
```

To handle Duration values which are float, you can modify the `computeLeavePeriods` function as shown below:

```
def computeLeavePeriods(prds: list, df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    row_index = list(df["EID"].unique())
    rows = len(row_index)
    cols = len(prds)
    rslt = [[0]*cols for i in range(rows)]
    for r in range(df.shape[0]):
        rslt[row_index.index(df.iloc[r]['EID'])][int(df.iloc[r]['wks_delta'])] += df.iloc[r]['DURATION']
    return pd.DataFrame(data= rslt, columns=prds, index=row_index)
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the approach. At the end, in fact in the line after 'for r in range...' it shows a TypeError as 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not numpy.float64'. I tried to convert the EID, DURATION to integers post the groupby stage but the error still persists.

Comment: If I round DURATION to nearest integer and then convert it to integer, it gives me an Index Error as 'IndexError: list index out of range' at the same line as mentioned in the previous comment. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post the complete error message beginning with TraceBack into your question.

Comment: IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/d4/wzhp8dts0nx745lfh2rtpkp00000gp/T/ipykernel_57158/2691307073.py in <module>
      1 error_type, error, tb = sys.exc_info()
----> 2 filename, lineno, func_name, line = traceback.extract_tb(tb)[-1]

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: How do you conclude this error message is related to the ```for r in range.....``` instruction?

Comment: surely I could be wrong there. What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't know, since the error message relates to code which is not apparent in your question and doesn't seem to have anything to do with a dataframe

Comment: Finally found a way to make your instructions work for my dataset. Converting the EID and DURATION to integers worked. x1['EID'] = np.floor(pd.to_numeric(x1['EID'], errors='coerce')).astype('Int64')
x1['DURATION'] = np.floor(pd.to_numeric(x1['DURATION'], errors='coerce')).astype('Int64')

Comment: Glad it worked out for you

Comment: I have provided an update which handles the floats a little more cleanly.